# Creating a user in Postgres Database

Tags: c#, postgresql, plpgsql, npgsql

Unable to create role when i connect using npgsql. Authorisation error.

I tried to `GRANT ALL` on rolesTable to ascertain if that would make a difference but same error.

```
CREATE ROLE roleName LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWORD ##### VALID UNTIL 'infinity' CONNECTION LIMIT 3
```

I thought the role would be created but instead I get `42501:permission denied to create role`. The strange thing when I login to the postgres database using the user using PgAdmin tool I can create a user by the GUI.

Comment: Are you connecting base and user in `npgsql` are the same as in `PgAdmin`?

Comment: Yes i use the same userid as in PgAdmin.